# Typing rules of coinductive types?

Tags: type-theory, typing, coinduction, types

Are there typing rules for specific coinductive types such as conat or stream, or even in general the M-types?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. I guess that something like [Copatterns: programming infinite structures by observations](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2429075) or [Let's see how things unfold](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-03741-2_9) could help you.

Comment: how is it vague?

Comment: I've tried to read [Let's see how things unfold](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-03741-2_9). Unfortunately it's a bit too hard for me to understand it.

Comment: I guess it is impossible to write normal typing rules because coinductive types cannot be judgmentally equal?

Comment: I found [these slides](https://www.irit.fr/TYPES2013/Slides/TYPES13Slides_Setzer_et_al.pdf) much easier to approach for a person like me.